# EF Core execute the same query on multiple databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I have multiple databases with the same schema/context and I want to query them all.
I want to execute the same query on each database.
I cannot use Linked Servers in SQL because the databases are created/deleted on the fly.
Is there some way I can create some extension method for the context, so the query will execute on all of them? (sequentially or parallel)

I have already done this for one table but I want something that can work for all tables, so I don't have to write the same code for each table.

```cs
ConcurrentBag<FindConstructionSearchResult> results = new();
Parallel.ForEach(connStrings, new() { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 16 }, dbConnectionInfo =>
{
    DB_DataContext dctx = DbHelper.Get_DataDBContext(dbConnectionInfo.DbName, dbInstance);
    List<FindConstructionSearchResult> sstavby = dctx.SStavby.Where(x => x.Nazev.Contains(request.ConstructionName) || x.Znacka.Contains(request.ConstructionName)).Select(x => new FindConstructionSearchResult()
    {
        ConstructionMark = x.Znacka,
        ConstructionName = x.Nazev,
        Database = dbConnectionInfo.DbName
    }).ToList();
    foreach (var item in sstavby)
    {
        results.Add(item);
    }
});
```

this is pretty fast, but I don't think it is elegant.

Comment: It is EF6 or EF Core?

Comment: It is Ef Core. Current version I am using is 7.0.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the basic implementation right, just need to wrap it up in a tidy method.  EG

```
public class ParallelEfQuery
{
    public static List<T> ExecuteQueryParallel<T>(IEnumerable<DbContext> dbContexts, Func<DbContext,IQueryable<T>> queryFactory, int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 8)
    {
        var results = new System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentBag<T>();

        Parallel.ForEach(dbContexts, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism }, dbContext =>
        {
            var query = queryFactory(dbContext);
            foreach (var item in query)
            {
                results.Add(item);
            }
        });

        return results.ToList();    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The final implementation I used is following:

```cs
public static partial class DbHelper
{
    public static List<ParallelEfQueryResult<T>> ExecuteQueryParallel<T>(this IEnumerable<DB_DataContext> dbContexts, Func<DB_DataContext, IQueryable<T>> queryFactory, int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 8)
    {
        ConcurrentBag<ParallelEfQueryResult<T>> results = new();

        Parallel.ForEach(dbContexts, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism }, dbContext =>
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = queryFactory(dbContext);
            foreach (T? item in query)
            {
                ParallelEfQueryResult<T> r = new(dbContext.Database.GetDbConnection().Database, item);
                results.Add(r);
            }
        });
        return results.ToList();
    }
    public static IEnumerable<DB_DataContext> CreateAllContexts(string[] DbNames, DbHelper.DbInstanceEnum Instance)
    {
        foreach (var item in DbNames)
        {
            DB_DataContext context = Get_DataDBContext(item, Instance);
            yield return context;
        }
    }
}
public record struct ParallelEfQueryResult<T>(string Database, T Result)
{

}
```

"DB_DataContext" is the actual DbContext I am using.
The method "Get_DataDBContext" returns requested context for given Db Name and Sql Instance.
I modified the return Type so I can see from which database the result is.

Comment: Do not forget to dispose contexts.